# Second y-axis does not line up with data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot two sets of data on a single figure, using two y-axes. I am having some trouble getting the data/axis label transformation correct on the second y-axes.

An example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# example data
df <- structure(list(x = c(25, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36.5, 38, 40, 
42, 44, 46, 51, 53, 55, 58, 60, 62, 66, 69.5, 73.5, 80.5, 88, 
97), y = c(25L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 
0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), y2 = c(281.8, 
283.4, 284.8, 286.3, 288, 289.8, 291.7, 294.4, 296.9, 299.6, 
301.8, 303.8, 305, 305.7, 305.1, 304.3, 302.2, 300.5, 298.8, 
295.1, 292.4, 289.6, 286, 283.6, 281.9)), row.names = c(NA, -25L
), class = "data.frame")

# transform data to be plotted on the second y-axis 
df$y2_trans <- rescale(df$y2, to = c(min(df$y), max(df$y)))

# plot 
ggplot (data = df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y2_trans), color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y2_trans), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~rescale(., to = c(min(df$y2), max(df$y2)))))
```

[image]

Superficially this looks good, but upon close inspection the red points and line, don't quite match where they should on the second y-axis e.g.

```
df[14,]
    x y    y2 y2_trans
14 51 0 305.7       25
```

The highest point on the curve should be at 305.7 on the second y-axis, but it is just below 305. I can see this an issue relating to my use of `scales::rescale` but I don't know how to correct it. Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue has to do with how scale padding is applied to the two scales. I don't understand the workings well enough to know if that's a bug, intentional, or unavoidable. It could be solved by making the relationship explicit.

```
df$y2_trans <- (df$y2 - 280) * 1.0   # 1.0 included here and below in case you want to adjust

# plot 
ggplot (data = df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y2_trans), color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y2_trans), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. / 1.0) + 280, 
                                         breaks = 280 + 5*(0:5)),
                     breaks = 5*(0:5))
```

[image]